# How to remove a span element from Backbone.js $el?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

`this.$el` has the following structure:

```
<div>
    <span class="orWord">OR</span>
    <span>...</span>
</div>
```

I am trying to retrieve the span with class `orWord` and remove it from the DOM.
In order to achieve it I tried this but it didn't work:

```
this.$el('span.andWord').remove();
```

Please let me how the above span can be removed from the `$el` element.

Thanks

Comment: Why not `this.$el.find('span.orWord').remove();`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `find()` to search for a child element:

```
this.$el.find('span.orWord').remove();
```

Comment: You can actually now just do `this.$('span.orWord")` which maps to `.find`

Comment: @Jack that would entirely depend on what `this` is referring to

Comment: The same `this` that your using for `this.$el` http://backbonejs.org/#View-dollar